# what's the api way to enable amazon dynamodb TTL (Time to Live)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I went through the doc for aws, there's only console and cli way, I want to know is there a api way for dynamodb ttl?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `updateTimeToLive()` of the `DynamoDbClient` class, that is part of [the official AWS SDK for Java](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/), has the following description:

> The UpdateTimeToLive method enables or disables Time to Live (TTL) for the specified table.